# Result of complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

If $f(z)=z^{-1}$ is integrated on a circle not containing the origin, what is the result?

My guess is that since $f$ doesnt have a primitive on $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ the result cannot be $0$.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the circle doesn't contain the origin, therefore $\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic on the circle(closed curve), therefore the integral is $0$.

Comment: Could you explain why? I have just started reading complex analysis.I know that if a function has a primitive,then integrating it on a closed curve results in 0.

Comment: @Anwita Bhowmik I would suggest you look up the Cauchy-Goursat Integral Theorem

Answer (score 0):

By homotopy, you integration path can be reduced to any point in the plane (except 0 of course) and thus you integral is indeed $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of $z^{-1}$ along any circle such that $0$ does not belong to the closed disk whose boundary is that circle is $0$.